# how to make submit button with 2 option for quiz like JEE or NEET Display quetions as per the selection

Tags: javascript, html

i want to make quiz for JEE and NEET with two selecting option of radio button if select JEE and enter Submit button then all JEE's quetions will appear or another webpage will appear and same for NEET.

```
function submit1(e){
    var ele = document.getElementsByName('course'); 
    if(ele.value=="JEE"){
        e.preventDefault();
        location.href="quiz_jee.html";
    }
    else{
        e.preventDefault();
        location.href="quiz_neet.html";
    }
}
```

here is my html code

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="submit1(event)">
                <input type="text" id="name" name="Full Name" placeholder="Enter Full Name" required><br><br>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="Email id" placeholder="Enter Email Id" onblur="validateEmail(this);" required><br><br>
                <input type="radio" id="JEE" class="course" name="course" value="JEE" required>&nbsp;<label for="course">JEE</label>
                <input type="radio" id="NEET" class="course" name="course" value="NEET" required>&nbsp;<label for="course">NEET</label><br><br>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```